# Is the background script of a browser extension (in Chrome or otherwise) accessible?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm going to publish an extension to the Chrome store soon, and hopefully to other browsers eventually. I have a secret key set as a string in one of my background JavaScript files. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the information will be available. The entire contents of the extension is available, including the background JavaScript file(s), to anyone who downloads the extension (for either Chrome or Firefox). While you can try to obfuscate the information, it is ultimately available.

If you should be worried depends on the sensitivity of the information you are storing. A more detailed discussion of the security issues would, probably, be more appropriate on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).